# AppleScript to Save Excel Chart as PNG Broken after Recent Update

Tags: applescript, ms-office, error

I've been using this code as part of a larger script for the last year. Yesterday I upgraded Excel to Version 16.10 (180210) and I keep getting an Parameter error -50, which I've previously associated with permissions to access a particular file or folder. As suggested in some other articles I've seen, I have Excel alias the path, but that no longer seems to be working. Any suggestions?

Here's the code:

```
tell application "Finder" to set pth to container of (path to me) as text 
set {wb, ws, chartName} to {"testChart.xlsx", "charts", "spend"}
set fn to pth & chartName & ".png"

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    alias pth
    alias fn
    tell workbook wb to tell worksheet ws
        try
            save as picture chart object chartName picture type save as PNG file file name fn
        on error errMsg number errNum
            log errMsg
            log errNum
        end try
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting the resolution here with the hope that it will help others not waste their time as I have over the last few days. It turns out that saving a chart as an image via automation (both AppleScript and VBA) is broken in Excel 16.10 and 16.11. I had to revert to Excel 15.41, and now the code is working again.

Comment: I can confirm much of the scripting library is broken since the unified code base in version 16 launched. We're up to about 25 bugs to file from my workplace so far that are impacting us directly. - See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/318477/5472

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation Matt. I submitted it to MS, hopefully they'll get to it quickly.

Comment: Sorry to necropost. Actually, I have a solution for this. But you have to tailor the code for different versions of excel. It seems that Excel for Mac 2016 has a security sandbox and you can only export charts to "secure folders". See https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac034.htm. I can confirm that one cannot use AppleScript alone to export charts as image. But I have a proven solution that uses BOTH VBA and AppleScript.